# Why when I click to type in my textfield does my "No" radio button get clicked?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

http://web.cs.dal.ca/~selig/serverside/assignment1/

See it in action here, at the very bottom radio buttons.

Here's my jQuery (pretty simple):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Reveals the email address field when option is selected
    $('#yes-radio').click(function() {
        $('.email-field').show(200);
    });
    $('#no-radio').click(function() {
        $('.email-field').hide(200);
    });
 });
```

Can anyone tell me why it's doing this?

Comment: Can you show us your markup?

Comment: Your `no-radio` label is wrapping both the radio button and the label/input for the email that's why

Comment: Email input is wrapped in the radio label

Comment: It's not happening for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line:

`<label for="no-radio" class="radio-label"><input type="radio" name="email-radio" id="no-radio" value="no"> No <label>`

Needs to be:

`<label for="no-radio" class="radio-label"><input type="radio" name="email-radio" id="no-radio" value="no"> No </label>`

Notice that you didn't close the label. ^

Comment: That did not fix it. See the upload.

Comment: It worked for me! Looks good now.

Comment: Hmm, okay, it did work. Weird, locally I'm having an issue. THANKS! :D

Answer (score 0):

The label of your 'no' button is still open (you wrote `<label>` instead of `</label>`), so when clicking the textbox, you click the label, thus activating the no radio box.